# How to call program classes of one project in another project if they are in same parent location

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel project which is divided into two different Laravel projects. I wanted to use the program classes of one Laravel project in another and vice versa. What is the best approach to this? (For simplicity our projects = 1stlaravelproject and 2ndlaravelproject and we want to make calls to programs of 1stlaravelproject from 2ndlaravelproject and vice versa.)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

My structure looks like this

```
www/
├─ application-a/
│  └─ composer.json
   └─ custom-classes/
       └─ MyClass1.php
│
├─ application-b/
│  └─ composer.json
   └─ custom-classes/
          └─ MyClass2.php
```

And the Namespaces and structure are very much the same in both the project.

Comment: you can communicate with api

Answer (score 0):

`PSR-4` and `PSR-0` autoloading, classmap generation and files includes are supported. `PSR-4` is the recommended way since it offers greater ease of use (no need to regenerate the autoloader when you add classes).

Assuming your structure looks like:

```
www/
├─ application-a/
│  └─ composer.json
│
├─ application-b/
│  └─ composer.json
│
└─ custom-classes/
   └─ MyClass.php
```

Under the `psr-4` key you define a mapping from namespaces to paths, relative to the package root.

`composer.json` `application-a` and `application-b` should have :

```json
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
        "Custom\\Classes\\": "../custom-classes/"
    }
    ...
```

Then, run :

```
composer update
```

Now, you can use your class (`MyClass.php`) from `application-a` and `application-b` :

```
use Custom\Classes\MyClass;

$myClass = new MyClass;
$myClass->foo();
```

Don't forget to add `namespace` in your class, eg :

```
namespace Custom\Classes;

class MyClass
{
    public function foo()
    {
        return 'bar';
    }
}
```

Comment: i have structure something like 

www/
├─ application-a/
│  └─ composer.json
│  └─ custom-classes/
      └─ MyClass.php
├─ application-b/
│└─ composer.json
│└─ custom-classes/
   └─ MyClass.php

And the folders have same name and the namespaces. im wondering if there may have a  naming conflict.
But thanks for you solution

Comment: I can't read your structure due to formatting problems. Can you edit your question?

Comment: Hey can you have a look again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67157318/how-to-call-program-classes-of-one-project-in-another-project